# Find out what database a CKRecord belongs to

Tags: icloud, cloudkit

How can (or, Can) I find out which iCloud database a CKRecord belongs to?

There should be four possiblities at this time:

- private
- public
- shared
- no database connection yet, if created on device

Comment: How did you get the `CKRecord`? You need to provide more context in your question.

Comment: What I mean is, does CKRecord have any information (in its set of metadata) on what database it belongs to? A CKRecord can be pulled from any database, or it can be created on device which would mean that it does not yet have a database connection which would lead to a fourth possibility.

Comment: If there is no such information in the set of metadata of a CKRecord (with the final answer to my question being **No there is no such information**), then that means that with any local cache on device we would all be responsible for saving that added piece of metadata information somehow for each CKRecord.

Comment: Btw I am getting my CKRecord solely through subscriptions and fetchChanges operations at this point.

Comment: We can retrieve from CKRecordZoneID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in `CKRecord` that directly tells you what database it came from. But you always know the database from the source of the record.

If you get a subscription notification or from fetching changes, you know the database from the `CKQueryNotification`, `CKRecordZoneNotification`, or the new `CKDatabaseNotification`.

Of course if you are creating a new `CKRecord`, there is no database yet but you must know which database you intend to use (public, private, or the new shared).

Certainly if you get a `CKRecord` from performing a query, you know which database was used for the query operation.

If you need to persist a local copy of the record and then later you need to load that local copy and send it to the proper database, then your local copy must include data telling you which database it belongs to. Since you can always determine the source of a `CKRecord` when you obtain the record, this isn't an issue.

Comment: As noted somewhere, I just store the CKRecord metadata for stuff in my cache, not the whole CKRecord. I would need to add the database source information next to that metadata then.

Comment: I just realized I would likely need to add zone name to my local cache too. Records, when cached locally, needs to be saved by database, zone and recordname, if I understand correctly, to avoid clashes.